# Make this LINQ statement return T instead of Task<T>

Tags: c#, linq, task-parallel-library, async-await

I would like the following statement to return an *IEnumerable of String* instead.

```
IEnumerable<Task<string>> @select = artist.Reviews.Select(async s => await DownloadFile(s.ImageUrl,1000));
```

Adding *await* in front of *DownloadFile* did not change anything.

Signature of the method being called :

```
private static async Task<string> DownloadFile(string url, int timeout)
```

How can I achieve this ?

Comment: Pretty sure it should be Task<IEnumerable<string>>, not IEnumerable<Task<string>> i.e. a Task returning an IEnumerable<string> not an IEnumerable of Tasks which each return a string(?)

Comment: That sounds better, yes :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First, understand your types. That will lead you to a correct solution. I assume you're familiar with `IEnumerable<T>` (a sequence of things); but `Task<T>` is new to many people. A `Task<T>` is a *future* - some operation that *will* have a result of type `T` at some future time.

If you have an `IEnumerable<Task<string>>` (literally, a sequence of *futures that will have string results*), and you want `IEnumerable<string>` (literally, a sequence of strings), then what you want to do is to *(asynchronously) wait for all futures to complete*.

You can (asynchronously) wait for multiple futures by using `Task.WhenAll`:

```
IEnumerable<Task<string>> @select = artist.Reviews.Select(s => DownloadFile(s.ImageUrl,1000));
string[] results = await Task.WhenAll(@select);
```

Answer (score 4):

Check out https://github.com/paulcbetts/linqtoawait, I wrote a library to address exactly this problem.